# How can I find matching numbers count using reduce method Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, iphone, xcode

For example, I want calculate matching 7 and 5 numbers in

```
items = [1, 2, 7, 5, 7, 8, 5, 5, 1, 7]
```

I have tried `filter` like this:

```
items.filter{ $0 == 7 }.count
```

**It works** But I want to know how is this possible with using of `reduce` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`reduce(_:_:)`** to get the count of 7 and 5 like so,

```
let items = [1, 2, 7, 5, 7, 8, 5, 5, 1, 7]

let count = items.reduce(0) { ($1 == 7) ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```

Similarly you can count number of 5s.

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan I'm not mutating result anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

### NSCountedSet

If you want to count the occurrences of an element you can use `NSCountedSet`

```
let items = [1, 2, 7, 5, 7, 8, 5, 5, 1, 7]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: items)

let occurrenciesOf5 = countedSet.count(for: 5) // 3
let occurrenciesOf7 = countedSet.count(for: 7) // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default parameter:

```
let counts = items.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
```

This will tell you occurrences of each item. Then you can perform filter or any other action you need.

You can find any count by just passing it:

```
print(counts[7])
```